# Django template not working - not rendering {{ }}

Tags: django, templates, view, blogs

I have followed a tutorial for making a blog engine and successfully integrated it. It is just this template that is not working, I have no idea why. What can be the problem?

Here is the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% post.title %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
<p>Posted on {{ post.published|date:"F j, Y" }}<p>

{{ post.description|safe }}
<br>
{{ post.body|safe }}
<br>

{% if previous_post %}
<a href="{{ previous_post.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ previous_post.title }}">
&laquo;&nbsp;Previous Post:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ previous_post.title }}
</a>{% endif %}

{% if previous_post and next_post %}&nbsp;|&nbsp;{% endif %}

{% if next_post %}
<a href="{{ next_post.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ next_post.get_absolute_url }}">
Next Post:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ next_post.title }}&nbsp;&raquo;
</a>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

And here is views.py:

```
def detail(request, sl):
try:
     post = Post.objects.filter(slug=sl)[0]
     try:
          previous_post = post.get_previous_by_published()
     except:
          previous_post = ""
     try:
          next_post = post.get_next_by_published()
     except:
          next_post = ""
except:
     next_post = ""
     previous_post = ""
     post = ""
return render_to_response('blog/detail.html', {'post':post,
                                        'next_post':next_post,
                                        'previous_post':previous_post,
                                                               },)
```

Comment: Have you checked in debugger, that correct variables are passed to template? What variables are rendered and what are not?

Comment: With all those bare `except`s, you're catching (and hiding) any possible errors that might happen. Take them out, and you'll be able to work out what's really going wrong.

Comment: It usually is not a good idea to catch all errors using `except`. It is good to specify exactly what you are looking for ie `ValidationError`.

Comment: I don't really follow you with the ValidationError

Comment: log all the vars just before rendereing and check if they have the expected result..

Comment: replace the last except: with this code: http://pastebin.ru/KaEsFkE3 and post here stacktrace that will be printed

Comment: yeah better take your exception handler out and you will see what is going on behind the scenes..

Comment: Thanks people! It says now "list index out of range" I guess it cannot retrieve the post from the list. I will look that up now.

Comment: you forgot `{% endif %}` for the `{% if previous_post %}`

Comment: I have it in my deployed version :)

Comment: Hey that list index out of range was some problem with the apache...and i did included that code but I don't know where the stack trace gets printed

Comment: is it maybe because I am not working on a development version but directly on a hosted one that I don't see the stacktrace?

Comment: "list index out of range" maybe you're getting that because `post = Post.objects.filter(slug=sl)` returns nothing and you call `[0]` on it.
Try printing it and see it in the terminal.
Also try [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404)

Comment: How do I print it and see it in the terminal?

Comment: In a production environment, you can't. Just run `python manage.py runserver` in your production environment and load the page over localhost. You'll see the errors in the terminal then, and then you'll know what to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out and solved my problem. Just wanted to post it here so someone can use it.
It was actually a n00b mistake.

So the {{}} weren't rendering because of the fact that there was nothing in "sl" which I calling upon as argument in the function. 
It was empty because I was following a tutorial and the tutorial didn't explain a very important thing about Django, and that is that the named groups can be added as arguments in functions, and I had no named group called "sl" in my urlconf in the appropriate place. So by adding this:

```
(r'^([0-9]{4}/\d{1,2})/(?P<sl>.*)/$', detail),
```

in the urlconf the problem was solved.

Thanks for all the guidance.